# Offering Jummah in house because it dangerous going outside

Tags: salat

Is it allowed to offer Jummah prayer inside the house when moving outside could be dangerous and/or life threatening?

How do we know our jummah or any other prayer is being accepted?

How do I make up for the Jummah prayers I have missed for months?

Comment: this question is more suitable now, with Corona virus pandemic spreading all over the world... unfortunately we don't have a solid answer here yet

Answer (score 0):

It's not allowed to offer Juma prayer alone, as that won't be a Juma prayer at all. In case you miss juma, you just have to offer Zuhr prayer.

A muslim should keep in mind the inevitability of death. So if the time of death has arrived, then even if one goes to masjid to pray Juma, or stays at home and pray, death will surely reach anywhere one tends to go and no matter what you are doing. So one should have trust in Allah and do what is right, As no one can change the time of death.

Comment: how do i make up for prayers i missed? the juma prayers i have missed?

Comment: There is no Qaza for Juma prayer, you just have to do qaza of Zuhr prayer, at place of Juma prayer

Comment: @farhan it might be worth offering the minimum number for jammat. Here is what I found: http://spa.qibla.com/issue_view.asp?HD=1&ID=1267&CATE=4

Comment: -1. Safety in Islam comes before worship.

Comment: Your comment is misleading the qaza for Jumua' prayer is praying Zuhr at place of Jumua' prayer as you correctly mentioned in your answer! And if one has a minimum of Jammat at home he could pray Jumua' at home if they fear from some kind of danger: One (man) as an Imam performing a short khutba and at least an other man who is ma'mum!

Answer (score 0):

To answer, "Is it allowed to offer Jummah prayer inside the house when moving outside could be dangerous and/or life threatening?". I would say yes, *praying* from house is allowed **in case of real severe hindrance**. I base this off the hadith present in both [Bukhari (668)](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/62) and [Muslim (699)](https://sunnah.com/muslim/6/35). I will quote the one in Muslim, because I feel like that one is easier to read. Though, I have linked both.

> When you have announced" I testify that there is no god but Allah; I testify that Muhammad is the Messenger of Allah," do not say:" Come to the prayer," but make this announcement:" Say prayer in your houses." He (the narrator) said that the people disapproved of it. Ibn 'Abbas said: Are you astonished at it? He (the Holy Prophet), who is better than I, did it. Jumu'a prayer is no doubt obligatory, but I do not like that I should (force you) to come out and walk in mud and slippery ground.
>
> وَحَدَّثَنِي عَلِيُّ بْنُ حُجْرٍ السَّعْدِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا إِسْمَاعِيلُ، عَنْ عَبْدِ الْحَمِيدِ، صَاحِبِ الزِّيَادِيِّ عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ الْحَارِثِ، عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ عَبَّاسٍ، أَنَّهُ قَالَ لِمُؤَذِّنِهِ فِي يَوْمٍ مَطِيرٍ إِذَا قُلْتَ أَشْهَدُ أَنْ لاَ إِلَهَ إِلاَّ اللَّهُ أَشْهَدُ أَنَّ مُحَمَّدًا رَسُولُ اللَّهِ فَلاَ تَقُلْ حَىَّ عَلَى الصَّلاَةِ قُلْ صَلُّوا فِي بُيُوتِكُمْ - قَالَ - فَكَأَنَّ النَّاسَ اسْتَنْكَرُوا ذَاكَ فَقَالَ أَتَعْجَبُونَ مِنْ ذَا قَدْ فَعَلَ ذَا مَنْ هُوَ خَيْرٌ مِنِّي إِنَّ الْجُمُعَةَ عَزْمَةٌ وَإِنِّي كَرِهْتُ أَنْ أُحْرِجَكُمْ فَتَمْشُوا فِي الطِّينِ وَالدَّحْضِ ‏.

[Sahi Muslim Book 6, Hadith 35](https://sunnah.com/muslim/6/35)

Note that I said, *praying* from home is allowed, and did not necessarily call it the Jumu'a prayer. I refrained from making a more definitive statement because I quoted the hadith and you can read it and think more for yourself. I have often been told that upon missing Jumu'a you pray Dhuhar instead because if you missed the two fardh of Jumu'a then you have likely missed the jamma`t or the khutbah and the point of the Jumu'a prayer is more so to gather, listen to the imam and then say the two fardh. Therefore, if one has missed the point of attending the jamma`t as well as the khutbah and then misses the two fardh on Friday, it makes sense to instead pray Dhuhar. This is just a chain of thought and I understand that this does not mandate much but you can do further research to extend your own understanding.

Further you ask, "How do we know our jummah or any other prayer is being accepted?", We can not. Allah is generous but this is not a science where you will have evidence, or receipts of a prayer being accepted. We should make our best efforts and hope for Allah's mercy.

"How do I make up for the Jummah prayers I have missed for months?", I am not an Imam so I don't have an acute answer for you. But, If I were to say then start praying Jumu'a and other obligatory prayers, give zakat and follow all the five pillars of Islam. Try and be a muslim to Allah; I recollect an advice which might be a hadith but I am not sure (so if someone can find it, do edit my answer). It was that if you want to know about that status of your repentance than it has been accepted if you have managed to refrain from whatever wrongdoing that you were previously involved in. I find this to be reforming because it causes one to rethink twice before traversing the same mistakes because if you have refrained from them thus far, as far as you know, you were forgiven.

> And when those come to you who believe in Our verses, say, "Peace be upon you. Your Lord has decreed upon Himself mercy: that any of you who does wrong out of ignorance and then repents after that and corrects himself - indeed, He is Forgiving and Merciful. [Quran 6:54](https://quran.com/6/54)

Hope I at least helped some.

Answer (score 0):

Assalam alaykum. The Jumuah is waajib and can be prayed at home for the pandemic. 
There is no dispute among the scholars that a congregation is a necessary condition for the validity of al-Jumu'ah. This is based on the hadith of Tariq ibn Shihab who reports that the Prophet said: "Al-Jumu 'ah is an obligation ( wajib) upon every Muslim in the community." However, the scholars do differ on how many people are required for al-Jumu'ah. There are fifteen different opinions on this question and they are mentioned by Ibn Hajar in Fath al-Bari. The strongest opinion is that salatul Jumu'ah is valid if there are two or more people present since the Prophet is reported to have said: "Two or more constitute a congregation."

Ash-Shaukani says: 'The other prayers are considered to be made in congregation if there are two people present. The same applies to Jumu'ah salah, unless there is a reason for it to be different. There is no evidence to show that [for the purpose of the congregation] its number should be larger than that for the other prayers. 'Abdul Haqq says: 'There is no confirmed hadith on the number of people needed for al-Jumu'ah.' Similarly, as-Sayuti holds: 'There is no confirmed hadith which states a particular number [for the Jumu'ah salah].'" This is also the opinion of at-Tabari, Dawud, an-Nakha'i, and Ibn Hazm

As for the one who missed out of negligence, sick or women then they pray four rakaah as dhuhur according to hadith

According to the Muhaddith of the century, Shaykh Albani said it  is in accordance with the view of the majority of scholars on this matter. In his essay al-Ajwabah al-Naafi’ah (p. 47) he quotes the words of Siddeeq Hasan Khan: Jumu’ah is an obligation that Allaah, may He be glorified and exalted, has enjoined upon His slaves. If a person misses it for some reason, there should be evidence that Zuhr prayer is required. The hadeeth of Ibn Mas’ood, “If you miss the two rak’ahs then you should pray four rak’ahs” indicates that the one who misses Jumu’ah must pray Zuhr.

Then al-Albaani commented on these words by agreeing with them and classing the hadeeth of Ibn Mas’ood (may Allaah be pleased with him) as saheeh.

And Allah knows best

Comment: These two sentences "The Jumuah is waajib and can be prayed at home for the pandemic. There is no dispute among the scholars that a congregation is a necessary condition for the validity of al-Jumu'ah. " are contradictory! And who made al-Albani the muhaddith of the century there are more knwoledgable people in the matter he omnly got fame due to his closeness to ibn Bazz who invented teachers for him in hadeeth science.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to your first question:** *(Is it allowed to offer Jummah prayer inside the house when moving outside could be dangerous and/or life threatening?)*

In this case, you are allowed to pray in house.

> "Be dutiful to Allah as best you can." (Al-Quran 64:16)

You can do your best by praying in home.

**Answer to your second question:** *(How do we know our jummah or any other prayer is being accepted?)*

There isn't any valid way to know if your prayer is being accepted.

**Answer to your third question:** *(How do I make up for the Jummah prayers I have missed for months?)*

You need to feel bad, then promise to allah you won't miss Jummah ever again and then you need to seek for forgiveness to Allah. Allah is the greatest acceptor of repentence.

According to some sunni scholars, you need to pray the missed Jummah prayers as Zuhr alone. [(Reference)](https://www.thesunniway.com/articles/item/198-calculating-qaza-salah)

Take care.

Comment: Jumu'ah prayer must be prayed in congregation AND inside a Mosque, you can't pray it at home, just pray Dhur instead if going outside is life threatening.

Answer (score -2):

While in gazwas and wars, one jammat of Muslims pray in mosque and other ppl guard them, they used to do for protecting themselves. So Muslims should do this.

Comment: Welcome to [islam.se]. Please go through [answer].

Comment: Well if you had a reference for a Jumua' prayer during a war or battle that would be helpful! But please consider adding references to your statements or at least a logical explanation! As is your answer is more likely to be a comment!